# combine two query result set and paginate the value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have two query result set for $users and $logged_action and merged both.If I use all() displayed all value.I want to paginate.If I include paginate(10) instead of all.I caught a error

> BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74: Method paginate does
>   not exist.

```
$users = DB::table('request')->select('asset_request.*')->get();
 $logged_action= DB::table('status_tracker')->select('status_tracker.*')->get();
 $users = $users->merge($logged_action); 
 $users=$users->all(); 
 return view('layouts.approval_view',['users'=>$users]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can join the 2 tables by the same key that merge works and then paginate the result?

Something like that:

```
 $users = DB::table('request')->
join('status_tracker','on' .... )->select ('asset_request.*', ....)->paginate (10);
```

also did not tested but you can try this:

```
$users = DB::table('request')->select('asset_request.*')->paginate(10);
 $logged_action= DB::table('status_tracker')->select('status_tracker.*')->paginate(10);
 $users = $users->merge($logged_action);
 $users=$users->all();
 return view('layouts.approval_view',['users'=>$users]);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: still searching solution